# How to connect old Yamaha PRS E423 keyboards to FL Studio and Sibelius/Finale software?

Tags: ableton, fl-studio

How to connect old Yamaha PRS E423 to FL Studio and Sibelius/Finale software? It has USB connection, but I could not find proper instructions.

Comment: This isn't a Sound Design question, it is a Customer Support question. Try the Yamaha Midi/USB drivers here - http://download.yamaha.com/search/detail/?category_id=16084&product_id=1056788&asset_id=37206&asset_file_language=EN